# how to get rid of the white space when hiding a subreport ssrs2008?

Tags: ssrs-2008, subreports

I am using SSRS-2008. I am using a `subreport` named **SubReport1** in my main report named **MainReport1**.
When `SubReport1` has no rows, I get white-space in place of `SubReport1`in **MainReport1**.
How can i get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subreport will be displayed in main report with the properties mentioned in the subreport itself. So, if reduce the row height, it will not affect the report display if there exist a value. In all other cases, you will not see a blank space over there in the main report. (The row boundaries also could set to 'None' values in main report)

Select the row properties -> under 'Layout' section, you could find the 'Height' parameter. Provide value for this parameter as 0.07938cm